# MS Cognitive Services - Face API - Person Group Training Status always returns "The operation was failed"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

When I try to get the Person Group Training Status (https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395247), the API always returns "The operation was failed" (but the train https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395249 returns 202).
Do someone know what can cause this error?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share a code sample? What language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take.

After you create a person group, you need to create a person and place him/her in the person group.

Once a person is created, you can upload their photos and then, you can train a person group to process it.

Answer (score 0):

/train returning a 202 indicates that training successfully started
/training returns various error codes and messages indicating what went wrong (the documentation link you included), and "operation failed" usually indicates something was wrong with the HTTP request.

It would be really helpful to see the code to debug further :-)